# How to call a SSIS package deployed in server using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, package

We have our packaged deployed in production server but there are 2 packages which we are executing on demand from application code using stored procedure. When I am trying to execute the package from application code it's throwing error

> The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Windows Authentication.

Any suggestion or recommendation will be a great help.

Comment: As the error message indicates, you need to use a Windows authenticated account to execute an SSIS package. Either change to Windows authentication or create a separate app service that uses Windows auth and invoke that to execute the packages.

Comment: Is it a parametrised call to the Package you're making? If not, you could set up an agent job to run the package instead, and have the application call an SP that starts that Agent job. If it's a parametrised called, then you'll likely want to look at the authentication method the application uses.

Comment: From a deleted comment https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/199053/2131 but yeah, you must have a windows account running these packages as the CLR methods in the SSISDB do all sorts of impersonation and that doesn't work with sql server users.